# How do I solve this lifetime error for Serde Deserialize?

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization

**Goal:** I would like to implement this trait without getting lifetime errors.

Dependencies: `pqcrypto-dilithium = "0.4.5"` and `serde = {version = "1.0.138", features = ["derive"]}`. Import this in Cargo.toml

Import:

```
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::*;
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::DetachedSignature;
pub use serde::ser::{SerializeTuple};
pub use serde::de::Visitor;
pub use serde::{Serialize, Serializer, Deserialize, Deserializer};
```

The Seriaize implementation functions properly but the Deserialization one has lifetime issues.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Keys {
    pub public_key: pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::PublicKey,
    pub private_key: pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::SecretKey,
}

impl Serialize for Keys {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: &mut S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_tuple(2)?;
        state.serialize_element(&self.public_key)?;
        state.serialize_element(&self.private_key)?;
        state.end()
    }
}

impl Deserialize<'de> for Keys {
fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: &mut D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where D: Deserializer<'de>
{
    deserializer.deserialize_tuple(2, Visitor)
}
}
```

The problem here is in the deserialize implementation for `Keys`. I am getting this error.

```
use of undeclared lifetime name `'de`
undeclared lifetimerustcE0261
crypto.rs(36, 5): consider introducing lifetime `'de` here: `<'de>`
crypto.rs(37, 20): consider introducing lifetime `'de` here: `'de, `
[E0261] use of undeclared lifetime name `'de`. 
[Note] undeclared lifetime
```

Comment: As the error message says, consider introducing the lifetime `'de`: `impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Keys`

Comment: Oh, seems like I didn't understand the error message completely, thanks.

Comment: Please always put the error messages from `cargo check` and not your IDE, they're far better.

Comment: Alright, I will do that next time

Answer (score 1):

Correct Answer:

```
impl <'de> Deserialize<'de> for Keys {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: &mut D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>...
```